# How to use nuget.exe from powershell?

Tags: powershell, nuget

I want to use the get-package command from powershell but everytime i try to use it or another nuget command, it brings up an error. How do i solve this?

Comment: And the error that is showing is?

Comment: That nuget is not a recognized command

Answer (score 0):

NuGet.exe can be downloaded from https://www.nuget.org/downloads, but that doesn't provide the PowerShell cmdlets.

As the [reference docs for NuGet's PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/powershell-reference) docs say:

> The commands listed here are specific to the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio, and differ from the Package Management module commands that are available in a general PowerShell environment. Specifically, each environment has commands that are not available in the other, and commands with the same name may also differ in their specific arguments.

So, NuGet's commands like `Get-Package` only work in Visual Studio's Package Manager Console.